# how to add namespace and schema through xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, schema

I have recieved multiple xml documents that I have to transform through xsl into one unifrom xml document.
I also have to add a namespace and schema to this result xml document. My problem is that I have to add the schema and the namespaces to this document through the xsl stylesheet and I have no idea how to do it. Although I've come a long way to figure out how to add namespaces, how do I give my xml result document the location of my schema through the stylesheet?

This is what I have in my stylesheet at the moment which doesn't work, because of the schemaLocation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:main="http://www.vm.com/main"
        xmlns:teleprompt ="http://www.vm.com/teleprompt"
        xmlns:warner ="http://www.vm.com/warner"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vm.com/main mainSchema.xsd"
        version="1.0">
```

And this is what I have where I want the namespaces to be used:

```
<album teleprompt:type="simple" teleprompt:href="http://www.vm.com/teleprompt">
```

I also need this above code to apply to everything in its tree.

There are four of these albums and only two of them need namespaces.
Please don't give me the answers breaking up the elements into templates as I'm not using an in my stylesheet.

Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: Consider to post samples of the different XML input versions and then the corresponding output you want to create with XSLT. And asking for help with XSLT but then requesting not to post solutions using templates is rather odd, how do you write stylesheets without templates? If you want us to help fix your stylesheet code then please show us the code and not only the start tag of the root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the namespace binding for 'xsi', which is http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:main="http://www.vm.com/main"
    xmlns:teleprompt ="http://www.vm.com/teleprompt"
    xmlns:warner ="http://www.vm.com/warner"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vm.com/main mainSchema.xsd"
    version="1.0">
```

How you will succeed without using templates is of course another matter.

Comment: Thanks I can't believ I left out that